# SQL select just one record from two different tables

Tags: sql, union, distinct

I´ve got two tables. Let´s say they are called users and msg_systems. 
Users contains userid, first_name and last_name.
Msg_systems contains userid and msg_address. Msg_address could be either an email address or a cellphone number.
Let´s say we have three users, Donald Duck, Mickey Mouse and Pluto. The tables looks like this:
Users:

```
Userid     first_name     last_name
1          Donald         Duck
2          Mickey         Mouse
3          Pluto
```

Msg_systems:

```
Userid     msg_address
1          12345
1          donald.duck@duckburg.com
2          67890
```

As we can see, Pluto has neither an email address nor a cellphone number (after all, he´s just a dog). Mickey Mouse has a cellphone number, but no email address.

What I´d like to achive now is to get this result:

```
Donald Duck donald.duck@duckborg.com
Mickey Mouse
Pluto
```

I´d like every user to be listed, whether they´ve got an emailaddress or cellphone listed. However, I only want emailaddresses, not cellphone numbers.

I´ve tried some UNION versions but I can only manage to get Donald twice, once with his emailaddress and once with no msgaddress at all (where msgaddress LIKE '%@%' skips the cellphone).

Comment: use left join  ....

Comment: what do you think of using a temp table

Comment: No temp table needed.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

for get also not matching result  you should use left  join

```
select a.first_name, a.last_name, b.msg_address
from Users a
LEFT JOIN Msg_systems b on a.user_d  = b.user_id 
 AND b.msg_address LIKE U.first_name + '%'
```

Comment: You forgot _where msgaddress LIKE '%@%'_.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are using `MSSQL`

Use `LEFT Join` with `LIKE`

```
SELECT ISNULL(first_name,'') + ISNULL(last_name,'') + ISNULL(msg_address,'')
FROM Users U LEFT JOIN Msg_systems MS ON U.user_d  = MS.user_id AND  MS.msg_address LIKE U.first_name + '%'
```

Comment: To concatenate character data, ANSI SQL has the `||` operator, not `+`. I _think_ SQL Server has both options. Some products have `concat()` function.

Comment: @jarlh MSSQL supports +

Comment: I know, but what about `||`?

Comment: `||`  will not be supported by MSSQL

Comment: OK. Note that `+ null-value` returns null.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

```
select u.first_name, u.last_name, ms.msg_address
from users u left join
     msg_systems ms
     on ms.user_id = u.user_id and
        ms.msg_address like '%@%;
```

It seems like a really bad design to have an email address and phone number in the same column *without a column that identifies the type*.

This looks for a `'@'`.  There are clearly other ways to distinguish the two, but this seems relatively foolproof.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below sql server query:

```
SELECT [first_name] + ' ' + [last_name] + ' ' 
       + Isnull([msg_address], '') 
FROM   [dbo].[users] 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
                  FROM   [dbo].[msg_systems] 
                  WHERE  Isnumeric([msg_address]) <> 1) f1 
              ON [users].[userid] = f1.[userid]
```